# print html on A4 page, media not working

Tags: html, css, printing, css-paged-media

I have requirement to print html page in A4 dimension, plus I want to print content body print along with css, html and ignore menu list, header, footer and page right-side menu list.

To start with this, I have introduce simple div and class noprint and add this in @media print but its seems not working. noprint class works outside the @media print so I know its correct.

Also my requirement is to print directly from browser using standard Ctrl+P keyboard option

```
<style type="text/css">

    .standardStyle {
        display:block;
        width:200px;
        height:150px;
        padding:10px;
        background-color:green;
        margin:5px;
    }

    @media print{ 
     .noprint{ color:red;}
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="noprint standardStyle">
    this is test line....
</div>

<div class="print standardStyle">
    this is test line....
</div>

<div class="print standardStyle">
    this is test line....
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the snippet and hit Ctrl+P , you will see the line in red colour.
Screenshot :

[image]

```css
@media print {
       .noprint { color:red; }
 }
```

```html
<div class="noprint">
        this is test line.....
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers do NOT print background colors and background images by default. I suppose you are missing the green background - this is the reason for it.

Usually this can be acitvated in the browser's print dialog, but to force a background to be printed you can only try adding `!important` to the settings that don't appear properly in print.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print
{    
  .noprint{      
    display: none !important;        
  }      
}
```